Using Tuned Model Gemini in Google App Script
I'm trying to connect the Gemini API to Google Apps Script using the following endpoint and it has successfully connected.
const geminiEndpoint = `https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash-latest:generateContent?key=${geminiApiKey}`;

How can I connect a tuned Gemini model that I created through Google AI Studio to Google Apps Script? Please note that I am using free tier of gemini API model (Gemini 1.5 Flash). Is it possible to do that with free tier model? If yes, It would be a pleasure if someone can provide the step by step process of it.


I saw your question from your comment @Tanaike I have a new question here link. If you don't mind, please take a look of it and maybe you can help answer it. Ref I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

I still got an error as I mention below in the comment. Maybe you have another suggestion?

I don't think free tier is an issue. Try 1. Make ytsure model name is correct, 2. Urlencode the model name and see if that makes any difference, 3. Send an Authorization header: {Authorization: Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOauthToken()}}

If you are using REST calls on your JS code, you can point to a endpoint like that: https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/$modelname:generateContent?key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY
You can find more details at the Fine-tuning tutorial page.

thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately I got this error when I implement it:
Exception: Request failed for https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "You do not have permission to access tuned model tunedModels/sample-document-tuning-..."*
is this error happened because I am using free tier of Gemini API model or what?
code:
const geminiEndpoint = "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/tunedModels/sample-document-tuning-xxx:generateContent?key=${geminiApiKey}"
